# How to execute a script on packer build failure?

Tags: packer

In my current template.json, I am executing a number of scripts with the shell provisioner. For example:

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "scripts": [
        "scriptA.sh",
        "scriptB.sh"
    ]
},
{
    "type": "shell",
    "scripts": [
        "scriptC.sh"
    ]
}
```

The current behavior I have observed is that, if there is a error in scriptA.sh, subsequent scripts do not get executed. However, I would like to have scriptC.sh no matter what. Is there another setting or proper location of scriptC.sh that would allow it to be executed on success or failure of packer build?

Although the 'packer build -on-error=cleanup' is present, I have not seen an option to add any additional clean up behavior on error.

Edit 1: I suppose I could combine all the scripts into one, perform a "try, catch, finally", and provide an exit code. However, for sake of readability and reusability, I would prefer to keep the scripts separate.

Comment: As far as I can see you can't really do what you want to, however, if you want to keep the scripts separate, you can also make the packer builds separate(have a json for scriptC and another for A and B). Another option will be to ensure that the scripts return `true` no matter what. Lasty, and the way I would do it, is to use ansible(chef/puppet/salt) - you can split your scripts into playbooks so they are well organized and you'll have better control overall.

Comment: In my particular scenario, I needed the "try, catch, finally" in scriptB and moved scriptC into scriptB (as the finally). @man0v, thanks for the tips! I'm curious though, how would having separate packer builds work to create one image? Since my goal of the three scripts is for the creation of one image.